# How do I make a symbolic link on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I've recently changed from Ubuntu to Windows 7.
One feature I'm struggling to develop without, is symbolic links.
In linux, I would simply

```
ln -s /where/to/ /where/from/
```

I've done some googling for Windows 7, but don't know what the standard accepted method is.

BTW I tried "MLINK" in the command line, and it said MLINK not found... - EDIT: As [Hello71](https://superuser.com/questions/165309/how-do-i-make-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-7/165310#165310) pointed out, it is MKLINK, I misread it.
Thanks!

EDIT:
I want to be able to include a php framework in this manner, as each of my projects all use the same library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a typo in your command; It's [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink), not `mlink`. I still recommend using [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx), mainly because it also allows for deleting junction points, unlike `mklink`.

Comment: ... does this not work with PHP include()'s or something...? I'm having a little trouble...

Comment: mklink worked whereas junction did not.

Comment: mklink didn't work properly either... it allowed me access to the files in the directory, but not files in subdirectories. I tried mklinnk with the /d, /j, and /h params.
with junction, I could paste the filepath into notepad and it would open, but with php's file_get_contents() it would not open.

Comment: Are you sure that Apache has permissions to access the target directories and files?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 SP1, **MKLINK.EXE** can create a *symbolic link* to either a directory or a file. But it can *also* create a *JUNCTION* link to a directory.

The ordinary DEL command (or any of the delete options in the Windows Explorer GUI) can remove any of these links, safely (i.e. *without* deleting the target file or directory - unless it's an empty directory).

The syntax is straightforward. Here is an example **batch (.bat) file** -

```
::  ** Location of target Directory **
SET DirPath=C:\TEST

::  ** Create Symbolic Link in Current Directory **
MKLINK /D  SymLinkName  "%DirPath%"

::  ** Create Junction in Current Directory **
MKLINK /J  JunctionName "%DirPath%"
```

Comment: Very funny - DEL *will* delete all the files especially non-empty directories w/o putting it into trash. Use rmdir instead. Thanks for nothing. Never trust anybody and especially not Windows OS.

Comment: Except that I've extensively tested this answer on Windows 7, and the DEL command works as described in my original answer in 2017. Perhaps you are not running Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a very simple method of creating a symbolic link to a directory on Windows 7.

1. Open a folder containing target folder in explorer.
2. Copy target folder to clipboard  via context menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
3. Open Start Menu folder in explorer, you may just type `shell:Start Menu`<kbd>⏎</kbd> in address bar.
4. Click right mouse button on an empty space of the folder to open context menu and choose Paste shortcut.

That's it.